# What are the restrictions of valid user name in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have searched the web with no joy, I want to know what restrictions joomla places on a valid username.

For example , min and max length.
Illegal characters.

Looking at the database field size, I assume the max length is 150, I have also read that {}[]- are illegal, but suspect there are other invalid characters.

Same question for the password, what's the size and character restrictions.

Thank you
Ben

Answer (score 4):

Username has a maximum 150 character length per the database and a minimum 2 character requirement. It doesn't have a restriction on {}[]- however does not let you use any of: <>\"'%;()&

Password doesn't have any limitations as it's hashed to salted MD5. The field itself is limited to 100 characters though the hashing will ensure that it'll not get that long.

Ref: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/table/user.php#L184

Comment: Thank you. I have written a little code to verify inputs fall within these parameters,posting it here for future reference. Probably a better way to do it, my regex fu is weak, but it works.

`<?php

$username="user";
$hash="dfc8a3c3361fde1s5ecf0213732582d1:6aYlDEj2Q40Aim90ke1T25buYyECHehA";

$ulen=strlen($username);
if(preg_match('[<|>|\"|\'|%|;|\(|\)|&]',$username)||$ulen<2||$ulen>150)
 echo "Bad User";
else
 echo "Good User";

echo "<br>";

if(strlen($hash)==65 && preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9:]/',$hash))
 echo "Good Hash";
else
 echo "Bad Hash";
?>`

Comment: In Joomla! 3.6.5 I have seen that a tab character in the username is stripped silently.